# Adding resque-web to Supervisord

Tags: supervisord

I am running `supervisord` to keep Redis and other pieces of software up and running. However, I can not, for the life of me, get `resque-web` to work.

This is the .ini that I'm including:

```
[program:resque]
command=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/resque-web
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
stdout_logfile=/var/lib/resque/stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/lib/resque/stderr.log
```

Unfortunately, when I run `service supervisor restart` I get the following in the `supervisord` log:

```
INFO exited: resque (exit status 127; not expected)
```

According to Google **code 127** is "Command Not Found". However, if I run that command manually the resque-web server boots up just fine with the output of:

```
[2013-05-24 00:03:09 -0600] Starting 'resque-web'...
[2013-05-24 00:03:09 -0600] trying port 5678...
```

It's also worth noting that I see the following in the `/var/lib/resque/stderr.log` when supervisord tries to launch resque-web:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory
```

So I'm stumped. Every other piece of software I've configured on supervisord works just fine. This is the only one giving me a headache...

### Edit 1

So I tried creating a simple bash script to get around this, and now I get a different error in the `stderr.log` file. The .ini I include is changed to have `command=/usr/local/bin/resque-web`

**/usr/local/bin/resque-web**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/default
resque-web
```

**Error**

```
usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/vegas-0.1.11/lib/vegas/runner.rb:82:in `app_dir': nor --app-dir neither EVN['HOME'] defined (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/vegas-0.1.11/lib/vegas/runner.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/resque-1.24.1/bin/resque-web:13:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/resque-1.24.1/bin/resque-web:13:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/resque-web:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/resque-web:23:in `'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that supervisor will not work with resque-web as it's a daemonized process. The solution was to create `/etc/cron.d/resque` and put the following in it:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin
HOME=/
* * * * * root resque-web
```

This runs every minute and reboots the server if it crashes. Good enough for me!